# If f: R to R is function such that for all a in R, the preimage of $(a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,a)$ is open, then f is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

[image]

I just need to show that the preimage of any open set is an open set. I can easily show that the preimage of any interval is open using the fact that the preimage of intersection is the intersection of preimage. The part that I am stuck on is what happens if the open set is an infinite union of open intervals such as (0,1) U (1,2) U (2,3).... In this case, the preimage would be an infinite intersection of open sets and I cannot guarantee that we have an open preimage.

Comment: It is enough to prove that the pre-image of any interval of the form $\left( a, b \right)$ with $-\infty \leq a < b \leq \infty$ is open. Take any open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, it is a union of these type of intervals so that the pre-image of $U$ is the union of pre-images of individual invtervals, which is open.

Comment: Why do think that the pre-image of a union is an intersection? It is actually a union.

Answer (score 1):

This is easier if you use the $\epsilon\text{-}\delta$ definition of continuity which is equivalent to the pre-image definition.

Let $a\in\mathbb R$ and $\epsilon\gt 0$ be given.

Then $f^{-1}(f(a)-\epsilon, f(a)+\epsilon)=f^{-1}((-\infty, f(a)+\epsilon)\cap(f(a)-\epsilon, \infty))=f^{-1}(-\infty,f(a)+\epsilon)\cap f^{-1}(f(a)-\epsilon, \infty)$

By our hypothesis, $f^{-1}$ of each of the intervals is open and, since the intersection of two open sets is open, their intersection is open. Moreover, it is an open set containing $a$ so there exists $\delta\gt 0$ such that $(a-\delta, a+\delta)\subset f^{-1}(f(a)-\epsilon, f(a)+\epsilon)$

Therefore, $f$ is continuous at $a$ and since this is true for any $a$, $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

This follows right away noting that $\{(a,+\infty), (-\infty,a)\mid a \in \Bbb R\}$ is a subbase for the (order) topology on $\Bbb R$: continuity follows when the inverse images of subbasic elements are open. The same holds then too for the generated base (as $f^{-1}$ preserves intersections) and then for all open sets (as $f^{-1}$ preserves all unions).

Answer (score 0):

Your doubt about the union actually isn't really a problem, because we can show that if a and b are real numbers, then $(a,b)=(-\infty,b) \cap(a,\infty)$ . This just means that $f^{-1}((a,b))=f^{-1}( (-\infty,b))\cap f^{-1}((a,\infty))$ which is the intersection of two open sets, so it is open. Now, any open set can just be seen an arbitrary union of sets $(a,b)$, which means that if U is any open set, then it follows that $f^{-1}(U)$ is just the union of open sets. The doubt you had was that you thought that the intersections were infinite intersections, but in fact , a set like the one you showed of the type $(0,1)\cup(1,2)\cup......$ is just an infinite union of finite intersections.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
\begin{align}
 f^{-1}(a,b)=\{x:a<f(x)<b\}&=\{x:f(x)>a\} \cap \{x:f(x)<b\}\\
&=f^{-1}(a,+\infty) \cap f^{-1}(-\infty,b) 
\end{align}
Pre-image of any open interval is open.